# How to configure IdleTime using IdleVue component in VueJs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vue-component, session-timeout

Below is the basic code I am using to get the Idle time for my application.

```
Vue.use(IdleVue, {
    eventEmitter: eventsHub,
    idleTime: 3300000,
    events: ['mousemove', 'keydown', 'mousedown', 'touchstart'],
    keepTracking: true
});
```

for application to stop and start idling OnIdle and onActive functions are used.

I need to make idleTime in the code configurable. This code is located in main.js file. I want to configure idletime from the component level(I havve variable in state of component, coming from API and based on that I need to set this idle time).

How can I achieve that? Thanks in Advance.